# Return Excel Spreadsheet using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have this method:

```
public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet createDoc()
{
    try
    {       
        app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
        worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write("Error");
    }
    finally
    {
    }
    return worksheet;
}
```

I need to be able to return this worksheet and append it to an html iframe in my view. I am using MVC4 in Visual Studio. Here is the code I have been using so far to get JSONResults, but I've never had to deal with this.

```
    $.getJSON("/exceldocumentmethod", function (results) {
    });
```

Any advice?

Comment: getJSON expects JSON to be returned? You probably just want the `src` of the iframe to be changed, e.g. `<iframe src='/myexcelaction?param1=foo&param2=bar' />`

Comment: @thaJeztah, you have basically hit it on the head. barnacle, much improved question. As I suggested before, consider returning a list of strings (json format) in csv format...

Comment: Literally could not have been more spot on. Dave A I did write the previous question in a bit of a fatigued rush, so thank you for your patience and advice. The issue is now I can't seem to return the excel spreadsheet from the method. I'm looking for something like public excelspreadsheet newSpreadsheet(param) { return excelspreadsheet }

Answer (score 0):

You should not use JSON for this. You should have a controller action that is returning the Excel file directly to the response with proper Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers. And then point the `src` of the `iframe` to this controller action. Don't use any `$.getJSON` methods, they won't help you.

So for example you could have the following iframe:

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("ExcelDoc", "Home")"></iframe>
```

and your ExcelDoc action might look like this:

```
public ActionResult ExcelDoc()
{
    var doc = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/example.xls");
    return File(doc, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

and for Excel2007 and above .xlsx files the correct Content-Type is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

Also I noticed that you are using Excel Interop to generate the document dynamically on the server. This librrary relies on Excel being installed on the server and was not designed to be used in a web application (server environment). Don't use it. If you want to generate an Excel file dynamically on the server you could use the [`Open XML SDK`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). Here's an [`example on MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx) how you could use this SDK to generate an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: The issue with this is it doesn't display in the iframe, it just proceeds to download the file. I am using google chrome.

Comment: That's probably normal. I am not sure that Google Chrome supports displaying Excel documents inline. Have you tried this in Internet Explorer?

Comment: I'm just struggling to find a simple way to generate excel documents and display them nicely in my webpage... without having to save the excel document. Can you assist me?

Comment: There's no way to do that reliably in a cross browser manner. Browsers that do not support the Excel plugin simply won't display it but prompt the user to download the file and there's nothing you could do about it, other than using some different format than Excel of course that browsers are capable of displaying inline. For example HTML is such a format I would recommend you using if you want to display some content inline. XLS is meant to be opened in specific desktop application such as Microsoft Excel.

Comment: So is there a way to generate an excel spreadsheet and convert it to html, then display it in a frame?

Comment: Why would you want to generate an Excel spreadsheet if you are going to convert it to HTML? Just generate the HTML that you will display to the user.